# Add an empty list as a value in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table in R where one of the columns corresponds to a list of strings, like this:

```
DT <- data.table(c1 = 1:3, 
                 c2 = as.list(c("bob",NA,"mary")), 
                 c3 = as.list(c(NA,"joe",NA)))
```

I would like to replace the NA value with an empty list, because I later concatenate columns c2 and c3, using:

```
DT[, combined := list(list(unlist(union(c2,c3)))), by=c1]
```

which gives me

```
DT$combined
   [[1]] bob,NA
   [[2]] NA,joe
   [[3]] mary,NA
```

instead of the desired

```
DT$combined
   [[1]] bob
   [[2]] joe
   [[3]] mary
```

I can get the desired result by converting the NAs to empty lists, and here is where my question comes in: how to do it in an elegant way?

I can get rid of the NAs using data frame syntax:

```
DT$c2[is.na(DT$c2)] <- list(list())
```

but, because I'm using data tables, and they should be better than that, I want to do something like

```
set(DT, DT[,.I[is.na(c2)]], "c2", value= list(list()))
```

To which R spits out the following error:

```
Error in set(DT, DT[, .I[is.na(c2)]], "c2", value = list(list())) : 
RHS of assignment to existing column 'c2' is zero length but not   NULL. 
If you intend to delete the column use NULL. Otherwise, the RHS must have length > 0; 
e.g., NA_integer_. If you are trying to change the column type to be an empty list column then, 
as with all column type changes, provide a full length RHS vector such as 
vector('list',nrow(DT)); i.e., 'plonk' in the new column.
```

I'm just looking for a better way to use data.tables.

Comment: Are you sure you want to have `c2` and `c3` be lists? In your example you seem to only keep a single value in them.

Comment: Yes, I didn't post my application code because it's much much messier, but they're lists of attributes with multiple values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add an explicit `NULL` to your `list(list())`:

```
DT[is.na(c2), c2 := .(list(NULL))]

# or loop over the relevant columns
for (col in c('c2', 'c3')) DT[is.na(get(col)), (col) := .(list(NULL))]
```